# BigQuery : Time Stamp of Next Events are Lesser Than Previous Event's Time Stamp

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, analytics, business-intelligence

I am trying to find time between LevelStart and LevelComplete events for a user through BigQuery.
Just for reference I am using Firebase and have exported data to BigQuery.

I have run the following query on BigQuery.

```
SELECT 
e.event_name, 
e.event_timestamp,
ep.value as LevelNo
FROM 
    `analytics_353710281.events_20240110` e,
    UNNEST(e.event_params) as ep
WHERE 
    e.event_name IN ('LevelStart', 'LevelComplete', 'LevelFailed')
    AND e.user_pseudo_id = 'b24e4ff743034ae7fe3a6cba3cc77045'
    AND ep.key = 'LevelNo';
```

This user_pseudo_id belongs to me and I have tested the app very well and have verified if all the events are sent to Firebase properly. The events being sent to Firebase are fine.

Upon Running the Query I got the following data

[image]

As you can see I have played and completed 4 Levels. The problem I am facing is LevelStart time for Level2 is Less then LevelComplete time for Level1. This is not possible, user plays level1 then completes it and then plays level2.
I have tried finding the difference in seconds by the following formula

```
(LevelCompletTime-LevelStartTime)/1000000)
```

This gives me time in seconds for which user has played the level.

**My Question:**
How is it possible that the time stamps of Level2Start is less than Level1Complete? What is it that I am doing wrong here? How can I fix it if it is not fixed I will not be able to get data accurately for each level.

Looking forward for your responses.
Thanks

Comment: hard to troubleshoot without schema and dataflow... but take a look at adding sessions if you have them... perhaps you played level1 again and that overwrote your original level1 try, or perhaps if you include sessions, you will see that you have multiple sessions per level1